# Understrap - scss stopped working, not reloading

Tags: css, wordpress, sass

I am following step-by-step this tutorial on developing a wordpress theme using understrap: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MoO-UsIvFIs
and at one point the page just stopped reacting to scss changes... no matter if i comment the scss file, delete it, whatever. Tried clearing cache, disabling cache, cache disabled in mamp too, clearing entire WP cache using a plugin - nothing helps.
Anyone got an idea how to fix this? I really want to finish the guide:p

EDIT: to confirm it's not a SCSS problem but CSS problem, i commented entire main theme's CSS file (css/theme.css) - it did not work, all styles still showing..

Answer (score 0):

if your running in your local are you doing this?:

**To work and compile your Sass files on the fly start:**

```
npm run watch
```

check also:

The css & JavaScript wasn’t loading because it was trying to use a different file in **enqueue.php**

Answer (score -1):

Check your bundler is still running, putting in incorrect scss can cause it to stop.

Comment: I'm sorry how do i check the bundler?

Answer (score -1):

got the same issue if you see his understrap version he is using the 0.94 one, in that version there is a gulp.js file which is missing on the latest versions!

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31973315)